# ng-show not working...Although IsShowRegister is getting true in Controller class on clicking the Register buttonr but not reflecting in the view

Tags: angularjs

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="This is social network site" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Social Network, Social Media, Make Friends, Newsfeed, Profile Page" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <title>Rafiki</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets
    ================================================= -->
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' />" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/style.css' />" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/ionicons.min.css' />" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/font-awesome.min.css' />" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--Google Webfont-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<c:url value='/static/images/favicon.png' />" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl" ng-init="ctrl.init()">

    <!-- Header
    ================================================= -->
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menu">
                <div class="container">

                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" id="rafiki" href="<c:url value='FriendBinder' />" >RAFIKI</a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-menu" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl">
                                        <form class="form-inline">
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email Address</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="example-email" placeholder="Email">
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" id="example-password" placeholder="Password">
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <fieldset class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="checkbox">Remember me
                                                </label>
                                            </fieldset>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Login In
                                                </button>                                        
                                    </form>  
                                    <button type="submit" ng-click="ctrl.showRegister()" class="btn-primary">Register</button>                          
                                </ul>                             
                        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Header End-->

    <!-- Top Banner
    ================================================= -->
    <section id="banner">
        <div class="container" >

        <!-- Sign Up Form
        ================================================= -->
        <div class="sign-up-form" ng-show="ctrl.isShowRegister" >            
                <h2 class="text-white">Find My Friends</h2>
                <div class="line-divider"></div>
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                        <p class="signup-text">Signup now and meet awesome people around the world</p>

                        <form  ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm">
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text"
                                        class="form-control" id="example-name" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="ctrl.user.name" name="name"
                                        required ng-minlength="3">
                                        <div class="has-error" ng-show="myForm.$dirty">
                                                <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">This is arequired field</span> 
                                                <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.minlength">Minimum length required is 3</span> <span ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid">This field is invalid </span>
                                        </div>

                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="example-email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" name="email"
                                                required>
                                                <div class="has-error" ng-show="myForm.$dirty">
                                                        <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">This is arequired field</span>
                                                        <span ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid">This field is invalid </span>
                                                </div>

                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="example-password" placeholder="Enter a password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password" name="password" required>
                                                    <div class="has-error" ng-show="myForm.$dirty"> </div>                                      
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <p>By signning up you agree to the terms</p>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn-secondary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Create Account </button>
                            </form>
                </div>               
        </div><!-- Sign Up Form End -->
    </div>
</section>

        <!-- Footer
    ================================================= -->
    <footer id="footer">

        <div class="copyright">
                <p>Copyright @Rafiki 2017. All rights reserved</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!--preloader-->
    <div id="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts
    ================================================= -->
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/app.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/controller/user_controller.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/service/user_service.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery.incremental-counter.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery.appear.min.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/bootstrap.min.js' />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/script.js' />"></script>
</body>
</html>**strong text**
```

//isShowRegister is getting true but signup form is not viewing.
'use strict';

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService) {
    var self = this;
    self.user={id:null,name:'',email:'',password:''};
    self.users=[];
    self.init=init;
    var message=message;
    var isShowRegister=isShowRegister;
    self.submit = submit;
    self.reset = reset;
    self.showRegister=showRegister;

    function init() {
        debugger;
        self.isShowRegister=false;
      }

    function showRegister(){
          debugger; 
        self.isShowRegister=true;
    }



    function createUser(user){
        UserService.createUser(user)
            .then( function (d){
            self.message=d},
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while creating User');
            }
        );
    }




    function submit() {
        if(self.user.id===null){
            console.log('Saving New User', self.user);
            createUser(self.user);
        }else{
            updateUser(self.user, self.user.id);
            console.log('User updated with id ', self.user.id);
        }
        reset();
    }



    function reset(){
        self.user={id:null,username:'',address:'',email:''};
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
    }

}]);
```

please check this, there might be some initialization problem as showRegister function is called on clicking and isShowRegister value is also getting true but signup form is not showing.

Comment: Sorry use strict is there in controller

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to do this:

```
var self = this;
self.user={id:null,name:'',email:'',password:''};
self.users=[];
self.init=init;
var message=message;
self.isShowRegister = false;   //<------------
self.submit = submit;
self.reset = reset;
self.showRegister=showRegister;
```